# Voltage fluctuations in TIP122

Tags: power-supply, resistance, load, voltage

I have used the following circuit diagram for power supply using a transformer,simple bridge rectifier and filter capacitor at the back of it to get 12V dcI have used the TIP122 as shown:
[image]

Idealy the circuit should maintain its output steadily as I change the output load. It only changes by changing the value of the resistance of poteniometer. In simulation every thing is working fine but practically I am getting a voltage drop each time i change the load and make it different. with smaller resistance even 100 ohm gives me a 2.4V drop from changing it from 4.7k to 100. What is the issue in this. Kindly help me.

Comment: Unless there is something in the circuit that is not shown, your supply is adjustable but not regulating. Voltage drop is to be expected. And do you really need 3!  TIP122s!!??!!

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy my read of the question is that the OP is looking for load regulation, not line regulation.

Comment: @EEK21 a TIP122 is a darlington, so it effectively has 2 base-emitter junctions in series in each one. You've stacked 3 of them, to you have 6 base-emitter junctions in series. At 0.7V each, that requires 4.2V to forward-bias them all. If your supply is 12V, then the absolute highest you can get at the emitter of Q3 is 7.8V with RV1 turned all the way up to the top.

Comment: @brhans given what we can see of the circuit, and knowing the input is rectified AC, I would not expect there to be load regulation.

Comment: Well - yes, considering that the source is just a simple rectified transformer, load regulation is also an unreasonable expectation with this circuit ...

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I just did it to increase the current gain. And reduce my voltage drop incase my single transistor is insufficient to provide the necessary current.

Comment: @brhans I dont have any problem with the voltage drop I will receive due to diode. Even if it gives 7.8V then it should stay at this voltage, not change with the load. The drop is there as I change load meaning for 10k i might get 7.8V but for 1K I will get 6.6V etc.

Comment: Your problem is that your output voltage depends on the value of your input voltage, and your input voltage changes depending on how large your load is (the amount of current it draws). You have no fixed reference voltage in your circuit.

Comment: @EEK21 The current gain of a TP122 is on the order of 1000.  Do you really want a gain of 1000x1000x1000 = 1 billion? (Hint: Unlikely)

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Nope...Ill change that. This was done because I felt the voltage drop might be due to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First, you use three Darlington power transistors in what's basically a triple Darlington arrangement. There's no reason to do this. You would connect transistors like that to get higher gain, but a single TIP122 is rated for an \$h_{FE}\$ of 2500 @ 4 A and will be more at lower collector currents (see charts in the [data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf)), so you only need a couple of milliamps to drive it. If you're going to use three transistors you'd be better off putting them in a parallel arrangement for higher current handling something like this where the load current is shared and the emitter resistances help equalize it so one transistor doesn't take all the current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYevlj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Next, you have the pot connected directly to the positive rectifier output, when the pot is fully clockwise there will be very little resistance between the rectifier output voltage and the bases of the transistors which could cause excessive base current if the load resistance is low, you should have some resistance between the pot and the transistor(s) to limit the base current.

Also, there's no regulation with your circuit. The output voltage will vary with   line voltage, with load current, and with temperature. A regulator needs a reference and feedback to keep the output stable, this circuit has none. There are plenty of resources out there on linear power supply design, do a bit of research (not those DIY Youtube videos where they show some parts being soldered together with no circuit board or explanation). ARRL Handbooks are one place to look.

Comment: Thankyou very helpfull.

Comment: By the way shouldn't it be the Ie=114mA.

Comment: @EEK21 Ah, let me rework that answer... not thinking straight today.

Comment: @EEK21 Okay, I calculated the base current incorrectly (forgot to factor in the voltage across the load), it would only be a problem if the collector wasn't connected or the load resistance was rather low. Still base current is one thing you have to watch out for and add a base resistor if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely have too many TIP122s! 
I don't know what gave you the idea, but one of them alone has plenty of gain and also a large voltage drop. 
The [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf) specifies collector-emitter saturation voltage ( V<sub>CE(sat)</sub> ) as: 
2.0 V(Max) @ I<sub>C</sub> = 3.0 A 
and 
4.0 V(Max) @ I<sub>C</sub> = 5.0 A

Additionally, the Base−Emitter ON Voltage (voltage needed to turn the transistor on) at 
I<sub>C</sub> = 3.0 A and V<sub>CE</sub> = 3.0 V is specified at 2.5V(max) 
which means that even at a lower collector current and Vce voltage drop, your emitter will still be 2.5 V lower than the base potential which can't be higher than your supply voltage.

Since you also have 3 such transistor Vbe voltage drops in series, the Vbe drops will add up even more, although not as much because every previous transistor will have a 1000 times lower current than the following one because that's the current gain of this model.

What you had intended to make was a simple emitter-follower voltage regulator, like this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCt8wr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you experiment with the load values, you will see that even this circuit has significant voltage drop and changes in output voltage, but significantly less than your circuit.

Another significant error in your circuit is that the RV1 is taking its voltage from the same rail as the output transistors - if that voltage is unregulated, any increase in load will decrease the input voltage, further reducing the output voltage.

ALSO, the way your transistor base connects directly to the positive supply voltage, when RV1 is set to maximum there is nothing to limit the current through the base-emitter junction of your transistor, which is similar to connecting two small-signal diodes (like 1N4148) in series from the input to the output.

What I suggest for you is to just use one TIP122, and provide some voltage regulation for RV1 if the input voltage is not regulated (like my circuit here). If you want to keep using your current circuit (minus two transistors), make sure to add a 1k resistor in series with the base pin!

Comment: I have used three Transistors just to reduce my voltage drop on changing voltage. As I thought the transistor might be facing an issue with providing necessary output current. From your point of view I feel like I should add a regulator of 12V at the base just to make the voltage regulator so that any changes of voltage due to load keeps it unaffected. Am I right? Also the three transistors voltage drop is though not a problem for me I just want a fixed output.

Comment: @EEK21 If you wanted more current, you would connect the transistors in parallel - right now they're in series, which does not increase your maximum output current, but it DOES make the voltage drop and regulation worse. Like I said, keep it to one transistor. You haven't said how much current are you trying to get at the output.