# Voltage fluctuations at potentiometer

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, potentiometer, voltage

I am using the following circuit which receives a DC voltage from a transformed and filter capacitors. I am getting a problem of the voltage changes.

[image]

Here without load the potentiometer input coming from the regulator is practically giving:

[image]

Without load the voltage I am getting across the load is:

[image]

With load the input voltage to the potentiometer becomes:

[image]

This input voltage change is not that much but this has resulted in a large change of 2 V in the output which is 9.2 V.

[image]

I haven't changed the knob of the potentiometer and I have received an unusual change. What can be the reason. I have used the potentiometer shown below:

[image]

This is the complete schematic:
[image]

Comment: What is the load resistance? What is the resistance of the 10 mH inductor?

Comment: The inductor acts as a short circuit in DC. thus its resistance is zero.

Comment: A real inductor has resistance. I'm assuming you are building this with real parts?

Comment: I havent used the inductor in the testing phase, its just for the PCB.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I was just reading the schematic.

Comment: If the voltage between the two end-terminals of the potentiometer is lower than 11.9V, then the regulator (U4) is dropping out. That could be because the regulator input is falling below 14V, or because the output of the regulator is connected to an excessively heavy load. I suspect the former. Without seeing the rest of the power supply circuit, or having an oscilloscope trace of U4's input, it's difficult/impossible to say more.

Comment: @SimonFitch I have shared the complete schematics

Comment: Is the transformer primary connected to mains? If so, it's dangerous to connect Earth to the transformer primary. Shouldn't the primary be connected between live and neutral? With the primary between live and earth like that, the secondary is unlikely to provide the voltage you expect. And if ever that earth connection breaks, your entire circuit becomes live.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Voltage fluctuations in TIP122](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670313/voltage-fluctuations-in-tip122)

Comment: Some changes regarding using a single transistor and regulator voltage at the potentiometer were suggested. These were followed but the result is almost the same.

Comment: @SimonFitch I have used the input from the mains Taking one as ground and the other as the Live. The mains is isolated from the circuit by transformer.

Comment: @EEK21 According to your schematic, mains-side ground and secondary side ground are the same node. That could end badly, unless your 120V/220V source is isolated from the REAL mains somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some good answers to a [very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670313/voltage-fluctuations-in-tip122) a few days ago, but you appear not to have understood and have not implemented the design changes required.

It would be very helpful if you would draw a schematic using CircuitLab or LTspice, so you can run simulations and see the effects of various component changes and design modifications. If you are making an actual breadboard, there may be some problems due to grounding and poor connections, especially if you are running more than a couple amps.

Here is a simple implementation of a variable 0-12 V power supply, set to 6 V, showing raw DC voltages for loads of 10, 100, and 1k, and control and output voltages for 10 and 1k loads.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsTxD5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Power supply voltages]

(edit) Here is a way to achieve nearly perfect correlation between a control signal and output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f551za.png)</sup>

[image: Control and output voltages]

Comment: I have done all the necessary changes mentioned in the last query. Didnt worked that's why am asking again. The simulation works fine on proteus.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Proteus, but you should be able to do a parameter sweep, or several simulations, and show the voltages and waveforms as I have done. It's hard to read the values on your schematic. And you should show your entire breadboard. No need to post an image of the DMM, when just the numbers would be sufficient.